# Erlang maps syntax error on one of my installations

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I installed Erlang on my Mac (OS X) and my Ubuntu 14.04 pc. Trying to create a map works on the Mac but the exact same code yields an error on my Ubuntu pc. I have tried it on one other computer and it worked there as well. This is the code:

```
Map = #{"hi" => 42} .
```

It's the sample code from [here](http://erlang.org/doc/man/maps.html). On my Ubuntu install it says `syntax error before {`.

Could it be some kind of problem with my version of Erlang? I installed it from aptitude. When I start it, it says "Eshell V5.10.4".

It is the same if I write the code in a file and try to compile it from the shell.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I get syntax error before: '{'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31589190/why-do-i-get-syntax-error-before)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Erlang installation is too old.  `5.10.4` was the version number of the emulator released in R16B03, while maps were introduced in 17.0.

If you need up-to-date Erlang packages for Ubuntu, you can find them [here](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/resources/download.html).  Either add the repository as described at that page, or scroll down to download packages manually.  (Full disclosure: provided by my employer)