# Why do I get syntax error before: '{'?

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell, eshell, erl

While playing with [Erlang getting started section](http://www.erlang.org/doc/getting_started/seq_prog.html#id59555)
I have met bizarre syntax error on trivial use case (simple map initialization). Are there any suggestion why does that happen?

> 1> `#{ "key" => 42}.`
>
> - 1: syntax error before: '{'

**Details:** Erlang R16B03 (erts-5.10.4), Eshell V5.10.4.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because maps were introduced in Erlang 17.

You have to upgrade your installation or do not use maps.

Comment: Thanks. Switch to the latest version (above v.17) works.